# Evaluate Performance of JSON.Stringify Function?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a Extjs form which has around 50 fields to search. I am posting form  data in JSON format to server. Before sending the data I am appying JSON.stringify method to convert the JavaScript object notation data into JSON form. but it seems after applying the function, the search operation has become slow. Is JSON.Stringify method costlier ? I want to know more details about the performance of the method, Please suggest alternatives for better performance.

Comment: The server side (how quick/slow it works) has nothing to do with how quick your JSON string is generated.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is so fast that you (human) won't be able to detect it. Problem must be somewhere else. If you don't believe me, measure it on [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/)